# ¿Cómo puedo activar el Internet desde mi aplicación con un Datacard (BAM)?

Tags: c#

Buenos días, estoy trabajando en C#, en una aplicación de escritorio usando [WPF](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation). Estoy trabajando una aplicación que debe de estar conectada a Internet de forma permanente, por lo cual se busca que esté conectado por medio ethernet, pero por sí en algún caso fallara dicha conexión, se quiere que el equipo se conecte por medio de una DataCard o BAM (Banda Ancha Móvil).

Investigando un poco sobre el tema, encontré una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40773/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-enviar-sms-desde-una-aplicaci%C3%B3n-hecha-en-c-sin-pagar-api-de-tercero) de SOes en la cual se habla un poco del como se puede enviar SMS por medio de esta tecnología cuando se tiene conectado un BAM al equipo. Ahí también aparece como enviar al puerto al que esté conectado el DataCard "GSM AT Commands", pero no encuentro que comando me servirá para lograr que el BAM empiece a servir para proveer de internet al equipo.

Otro detalle es que cuando se instala el controlador del dispositivo, también se instala un programa para poder realizar dicha función, en la cual se configuran todos los parámetros (APN, modo de autenticación - CHAP - y que se establezcan la IP y el WINS de manera dinámica)

Sí alguien supiera que comando se le debe de enviar al puerto para conectar a internet o si existe algún SDK o librería para facilitar esta tarea favor hacérmelo saber. Muchas gracias de ante mano.

**BAM**

[image: BAM]

Comment: Me parece que eso depende del contrato que tengas con el operador

Comment: La memoria BAM si me da acceso a internet, se tiene el plan de datos y funciona, como dice la pregunta, pero solo usando un programa que se instala en la Computadora. Lo que deseo es poder activar el BAM desde el sistema en C#

Comment: esa activación, sin usar código, ¿Cómo se realiza?