# ¿Es posible utilizar El modem alcatel One Touch para un sistema de notificación sms?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows, email, sms

que tal?
Actualmente estoy desarrollando un servicio de windows para enviar notificaciones via email y sms usando C#.
Actualmente busco especificaciones con las herramientas para las notificaciones sms y la empresa donde laboro tiene dispositivo con modelo **modem alcatel One Touch Link Y858**
con chip con saldo ilimitado de una compañia terceros.

He buscado aplicaciones para envio de sms (como el siguiente enlace: 
[[¿Cómo puedo enviar SMS desde una aplicación hecha en c# sin pagar API de terceros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40773/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-enviar-sms-desde-una-aplicaci%C3%B3n-hecha-en-c-sin-pagar-api-de-tercero][1])
)
para envio de notificaciones, pero mi duda es que si el dispositivo que describo servirá y sino cual me recomendarian.

Muchas gracias por cualquier respuesta.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo lo unico que necesitas es tener la comunicacion con el dispositivo para trasmitir el sms

Comment: ¿Has visto si trae alguna API?

Comment: Entiendo que al conectar un modem de banda ancha o modem gsm utilizan un puerto com1 virtual para comunicarse con la pc, segun el ejemplo del enlace que muestro en la declaración de la pregunta, la aplicación se comunica con el puerto com1, pero con el dispositivo que yo tengo no se muestra o no envia mensaje via sms con comando AT.